# jQuery DataTables plugin: Make specific row bold

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using the JQuery DataTables plugin found [here](http://datatables.net/).  I'd like to make a specific row bold (a Totals row).  How can I do so?

Right now I am trying to apply the CSS using `mRender`.  I've tried `fnRowCallback` and also tried using `.addClass` instead of `.css`.  Nothing seems to work.

**JS:**

```
"mRender": function (data) {
   if (data == "Totals") {
       $('#tblStatistics tbody tr td').css('font-weight', 'bold');
   }
   return data;
},
```

**My HTML is something like the below:**

```
<table id="tblStatistics">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow) {
     $(nRow).css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a little explanation to go with your code.

Comment: Please edit with more explanation to the answer so other developers can find this more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fnRowCallback like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            /* All cells in 4th row will be bolded  */
            if ( iDisplayIndex == 3 ) {
                $('td', nRow).each(function(){
                               $(this).html( '<td><b>'+$(this).text()+'</b><td>' );
                            });
            }
            return nRow;
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [ {
                "sClass": "center",
                "aTargets": [ -1, -2 ]
        } ]
    } );
} );
```

[JSFIDDLE - Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eVL4s/)

Comment: Tried this already.  Didn't work.  Besides, this only makes one cell bold, not the entire row.

Comment: Did you check the demo attached at the bottom ? It's making all cells with 4 index bold. You can just replace that if() with $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>' + aData[4] + '</b>' );

Comment: Yep.  I found that example from here (http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) for those who want the source.  Doesn't work.

Comment: You mean last column??  I need the row highlighted, not the column.  And the entire column isn't highlighted because of one specific value.    Each cell with a value of "A" is highlighted.

Comment: Ouch .. I've updated the code above .. here is updated jsfiddle link also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVL4s/)

Comment: Yeah, it makes that one row bold, but you still use `fnRowCallback`.  Only the `mRender` function has worked for me.

Comment: For the footer totals row you could use another callback, here is link to the [documentation/example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    if(iDisplayIndex == 3 /*Alternative Condition: aData[0] == "Totals"*/) {
        $(nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
    //OR
        $(nRow).addClass('yourCssClassHere');
    }
}
```

Don't use mRender for row highlighting. mRender is for columns. Use fnRowCallback for styling particular rows. If fnRowCallback wasn't working for you, please show us what you tried with fnRowCallback.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable({
                "fnRowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                    if ( data.status === "2") {
                        $(row).addClass('highlight');
                    }
                },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aaData": dataTab,
                "aoColumns": [{ "mDataProp": "state" }, { "mDataProp": "S_key_name" }, { "mDataProp": "nombre" }, { "mDataProp": "solicitante_id" }, { "mDataProp": "S_register_date" }, { "mDataProp": "S_desired_date" }, { "mDataProp": "T_Fecha_Estimada" }, { "mDataProp": "S_solicit_priority" }, { "mDataProp": "Edit" }],
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "aaSorting": [[5, "desc"]],
                "bJQueryUI": true
            });
```

Image working

[image]